# Yii2 ActiveQuery join keep returns unique record values

Tags: mysql, yii2, unique, right-join

main table

```
CREATE TABLE `orders` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nama` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lng` float(10,6) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

second table

```
CREATE TABLE `order_seller_detail` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `order_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sequence` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  
)
```

I am facing issue when it try to using right join. it return only unique rows. but their are multiple record in table order_seller_detail  associate with orders table with id. it should be multiple rows.
My Code:

```
 $query = Order::find()
         ->rightJoin('order_seller_detail', 'order_seller_detail.order_id=orders.id')
        ->all();
```

I also used following command to print query:

```
$query = Order::find()
         ->rightJoin('order_seller_detail', 'order_seller_detail.order_id=orders.id');
$query->createCommand()->getRawSql();
```

```
SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` RIGHT JOIN `order_seller_detail` ON rder_seller_detail.order_id=orders.id
```

when i run this query manually its working fine and give multiple row for same order, but when i user with yii2 active record its given me only unique row.

Please help

Thanks & Regards,
Baljit

Comment: a right join would also add order_seller_detail that have no order, but that should be impossible, so use a join and skip the right

Comment: Thansk for you quick reply, i used with 
 ->join('RIGHT JOIN','order_seller_detail', 'order_seller_detail.order_id = orders.id') but same issue return distnict order

Comment: the issue is not the join, have you tried the select directly in your database?

Comment: @nbk  yes we tried to run query manually in database , the result is fin and showing me multiple main table record SELECT `orders`.* FROM `orders` RIGHT JOIN `order_seller_detail` ON rder_seller_detail.order_id=orders.id. but its giving not same result when i user yii2 activequery

Answer (score 0):

you are only selecting orders, so you get only rows from `orders` but you also need to add at least one column from `order_seller_detail`

```
 $query = Order::find()
->select([
        'orders.*', // select all ordersfields
        'order_seller_detail.*' // select all order_seller_detail fields   ])
->Join('order_seller_detail', 'order_seller_detail.order_id=orders.id')
        ->all()
```

The resulting query is then

```
SELECT 
    `orders`.*
    ,`order_seller_detail`.*
FROM
    `orders`
        JOIN
    `order_seller_detail` ON rder_seller_detail.order_id = orders.id
```

As an example

> ```
> CREATE TABLE orders (id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO orders  VALUES  (1),(2);
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE order_seller_detail(id int,order_id int)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO order_seller_detail VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,2),(4,2)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     `orders`.*
>     ,`order_seller_detail`.*
> FROM
>     `orders`
>         JOIN
>     `order_seller_detail` ON order_seller_detail.order_id = orders.id
> ```
>
> ```
> id | id | order_id
> -: | -: | -------:
>  1 |  1 |        1
>  1 |  2 |        1
>  2 |  3 |        2
>  2 |  4 |        2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e029ae96c7d70a981a018b7b1ec199b)*

Comment: Thanks, i treid that but not working, same result. their is one record in orders table and two records in order_seller_detail with order_id associtve with order.id. now  we want there should display two row , but i am getting one row for orders.

Comment: that is strange, see my example,  the query should run just fine. see if you can reproduce your result

Comment: https://jsonblob.com/64ec4613-6fbd-11eb-8f1d-55a0eff15692

 "order": [
            {
                "id": "210",
                "order_seller_detail_id": "308",
                "order_id": "210"
            },
            {
                "id": "211",
                "order_seller_detail_id": "309",
                "order_id": "211"
            }
            
        ]

but it give me above result in yii2 activeRecord, order id 211 has two record in order_seller_detail. but it show me only one. their should be two. although when run query manaully its fine on database

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use your model relation? For example

```
$orders = Order::find()
->joinWith('orderSellerDetails')
->all();
```

then:

```
foreach($orders as $order){
    $sellerDetails = $order->orderSellerDetails; // your multirows from table 'order_seller_details' to current order
}
```

Your model relation must be like this:

```
public function getOrderSellerDetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OderSellerDetail::className(), ['order_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

Or if you use `gridview` just select data first from `order_seller_detail`, because gridview group your rows

Like:

```
$query = OrderSellerDetail::find()
->joinWith('order');

$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => $query,
]);
```